# Correct way to handle exception on Python2.6

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.6

I had an Python script that running continuously. If there any new file on directory then the python will open url using urllib2 to do some request on specific ip.

here are the code

```
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
values = dumps({
    'image_data':encoded_string,
    'requestCode':'111'
})

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
request = Request("http:/xx.xxx.xx.xxx/api/carplate_service",data=values, headers=headers)
response = urlopen(request, timeout=60)
```

The code are working well but on random time, let say usually happened on 1-2 AM then I got this error:

```
<class 'urllib2.URLError'> - <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

I had an exception on that function on this bellow :

```
try:
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    histId = int(sys.argv[2])
    handler = ModHandler()
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
    wdd = wm.add_watch('./' + ip + '/', pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
    notifier.loop()
except BaseException as e:
    with open("error.log", "a") as text_file:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        text_file.write( time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " [" + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno) + " - " + fname + "] : " + str(exc_type) + " - " +  str(e) + "\n")
        text_file.close();
```

The exception not working well because application cannot continue if there are some error like above.

My question are how to make program still continue even the exception throw?

I'm using python2.6

Thanks

Comment: write this in function and call function in catch block. may be with some delay or timeout.

Answer (score 0):

For function calls that go out to external services I usually find that the following basic structure works pretty well

```
import time

expire_time = 2

while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        # Do something here
        # ....
        # If you make it to the bottom of the code, break out of the loop
        break
    except BaseException as e:
        # Compare the start_time with the current time
        now_time = time.time()
        if now_time > start_time + expire_time:
            raise e

        # Otherwise try executing the `try` block again
```

Using the code that you've provided it could look something like this

```
import time

expire_time = 2

while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        ip = sys.argv[1]
        histId = int(sys.argv[2])
        handler = ModHandler()
        wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
        notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
        wdd = wm.add_watch('./' + ip + '/', pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE)
        notifier.loop()
        break
    except BaseException as e:
        now_time = time.time()
        if now_time > start_time + expire_time:
            raise e
        else:
            with open("error.log", "a") as text_file:
                exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                text_file.write( time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " [" + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno) + " - " + fname + "] : " + str(exc_type) + " - " +  str(e) + "\n")
                text_file.close();
```

Comment: Why you use time? whats the matter with that?

Comment: In my example you continue executing code inside the `try` block until it eventually makes it to the end and executes `break`. But if a `BaseException` is thrown after 2 seconds have passed, it will throw an error similar to what you have

Comment: It means that the code will continue executing, catching exceptions and then retrying for up to 2 seconds

Comment: What raise mean in python?

Comment: `raise` means raise an exception https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions